# Есть ли способ узнать, сколько записей было вставлено командой INSERT IGNORE?

Tags: mysql

Есть ли способ узнать, сколько записей было вставлено командой `INSERT IGNORE`? Сколько строк было добавлено или сколько проигнорировано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть. SQL функция `ROW_COUNT()` или апи функция `mysql_affected_rows()`